# How to make object-fit work with .gif files

Tags: html, css

Trying `object-fit` with a `.gif` image but `.gif` doesn't seem to be a supported file format?

MDN nor W3C say anything about `.gif` file and `object-fit` usage. They only mention "replaced elements", such as `<img>` but `<img>` supports `.gif's` so I'm confused why it's not working?

What am I doing wrong?

I have a `.jpg` and with that image it works fine.

HTML:

```
<div class="gif_container">
   <img class="animated_gif" src="~/img/1.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gif_container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.animated_gif {
    width: 372px;
    height: 664px;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#the-object-fit

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my .gif file... generated in Photoshop CS6... Works with a random one from the interwebs... investigating...

Comment: I think I might have found the error. Apparently you need to set the height and width of your image/artboard in Photoshop. Just importing the video as layers isn't enough.